# VS2012 Editor can't open include files but compiler is successful

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to use opencv in my project. Therefore i made a property sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>opencv_core249d.lib;opencv_imgproc249d.lib;opencv_highgui249d.lib;opencv_ml249d.lib;opencv_video249d.lib;opencv_features2d249d.lib;opencv_calib3d249d.lib;opencv_objdetect249d.lib;opencv_contrib249d.lib;opencv_legacy249d.lib;opencv_flann249d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

The VS2012 Editor gives me an error at the include directive:

```
Error: can not open source file opencv2/core/core.hpp
```

The functions are also unknown.

Nevertheless the compiler is successful and the application runs properly.

Within another project (same solution) with the same property sheet everything works fine.

I tried to reload the project and to restart VS2012 but the problem remains. I'm new to VS and have no more ideas.

Please tell if you need further information.

Comment: I am not too sure but it could very well possibly be a bug with the compiler.

Comment: When in doubt, shutdown the IDE, run to your solution folder, wipe out the SDF database, reopen the solution, and let the SDF rebuild completely (a practice I have automated as flakey as VS can be for some larger projects and source bases). Best of luck.

Comment: How is OPENCV_DIR defined?  If you made it an environment variable then the most obvious explanation is that VS is still running without that variable defined.  Logout + login usually takes care of that.  Consider making it a macro instead, that way you still have some hope to compile your program 2 years from now.

Comment: Deleting the SDF File solved the problem! (and also some other minor problems regarding some warnings about libraries while compiling)